# How to fill memory fast with a `int32_t` value?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, memory

Is there a function (SSEx intrinsics is OK) which will fill the memory with a specified `int32_t` value? For instance, when this value is equal to `0xAABBCC00` the result memory should look like:

```
AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00
AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00
AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00
AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00AABBCC00
...
```

I could use `std::fill` or simple for-loop, but it is not fast enough.

---

Resizing of a vector performed only once in the beginning of program, this is not an issue. The bottleneck is filling the memory.

Simplified code:

```
struct X
{
  typedef std::vector<int32_t> int_vec_t;
  int_vec_t buffer;

  X() : buffer( 5000000 ) { /* some more action */ }
  ~X() { /* some code here */ }

  // the following function is called 25 times per second
  const int_vec_t& process( int32_t background, const SOME_DATA& data );
};

const X::int_vec_t& X::process( int32_t background, const SOME_DATA& data )
{
    // the following one string takes 30% of total time of #process function
    std::fill( buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), background );

    // some processing
    // ...

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you code it yourself using SSE instructions ? You have the movxxxx instructions to move memory around (128 bits at a time). It is only one loop and moves, it shouldn't be difficult to do.

Comment: I'll admit I'm a little curious as to what your use case for this could possibly be that makes a for loop not fast enough. Are you just dealing with a tremendous block of memory? Does your platform suck at branching? Do you do this frequently in a high-performance app, like a game or something?

Comment: @Alexandre C., SSE instructions is OK, but I thought that maybe there is already some function in WinAPI. I don't want to invent a wheel.

Comment: Can you post code so we can see exactly what you're doing? That might help us figure out why it's being slow. Also, how big a vector are we talking? A couple hundred? A couple hundred thousand?

Comment: @Sean Edwards, I've added the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your answers. I've checked [wj32's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212649/how-to-fill-memory-fast-with-a-int32-t-value/3212751#3212751) , but it shows very similar time as `std::fill` do. My current solution works 4 times faster (in Visual Studio 2008) than `std::fill` with help of the function `memcpy`:

```
 // fill the first quarter by the usual way
 std::fill(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + buffer.size()/4, background);
 // copy the first quarter to the second (very fast)
 memcpy(&buffer[buffer.size()/4], &buffer[0], buffer.size()/4*sizeof(background));
 // copy the first half to the second (very fast)
 memcpy(&buffer[buffer.size()/2], &buffer[0], buffer.size()/2*sizeof(background));
```

In the production code one needs to add check if `buffer.size()` is divisible by 4 and add appropriate handling for that.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I would do it (please excuse the Microsoft-ness of it):

```
VOID FillInt32(__out PLONG M, __in LONG Fill, __in ULONG Count)
{
    __m128i f;

    // Fix mis-alignment.
    if ((ULONG_PTR)M & 0xf)
    {
        switch ((ULONG_PTR)M & 0xf)
        {
            case 0x4: if (Count >= 1) { *M++ = Fill; Count--; }
            case 0x8: if (Count >= 1) { *M++ = Fill; Count--; }
            case 0xc: if (Count >= 1) { *M++ = Fill; Count--; }
        }
    }

    f.m128i_i32[0] = Fill;
    f.m128i_i32[1] = Fill;
    f.m128i_i32[2] = Fill;
    f.m128i_i32[3] = Fill;

    while (Count >= 4)
    {
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)M, f);
        M += 4;
        Count -= 4;
    }

    // Fill remaining LONGs.
    switch (Count & 0x3)
    {
        case 0x3: *M++ = Fill;
        case 0x2: *M++ = Fill;
        case 0x1: *M++ = Fill;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be interested in how do this compare performancewise with std::fill.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a plain C guy. I don't know anything about std, fill or std::fill.

Comment: so you use intrinsic SSE instructions ... but this is done automatically by any decent compiler e.g. gcc or icpc for you when you write the vanilla for-loop. So I think there is no need.

Answer (score 6):

I have to ask: Have you definitely profiled `std::fill` and shown it to be the performance bottleneck? I would guess it to be implemented in a pretty efficient manner, such that the compiler can automatically generate the appropriate instructions (for example `-march` on gcc).

If it is the bottleneck, it may still be possible to get better benefit from an algorithmic redesign (if possible) to avoid setting so much memory (apparently over and over) such that it doesn't matter anymore which fill mechanism you use.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using

```
vector<int32_t> myVector;
myVector.reserve( sizeIWant );
```

and then use std::fill?  Or perhaps the constructor of a `std::vector` which takes as an argument the number of items held and the value to initialize them at?

Comment: This is a really good point. If you're appending to a vector, part of your overhead may be in resizing that vector, which wouldn't happen every time you inserted to the end (vector auto-expands a little larger than you need it, generally) but it would be often enough to incur a performance hit. Use reserve() to pre-allocate a certain length.

Comment: You can also use an array to be 100% sure resizing is not the issue.

Comment: Yeah, originally I thought he was trying to set values in an array he made with malloc(). I didn't even consider that it might be vector resizing slowing him down. :)

Comment: Resizing of a `vector` performed only once in the beginning of program, this is not an issue. The bottleneck is filling the memory.

Comment: Wow, you're in a whole new realm.  Is a `malloc` and `memcpy` solution too slow?

Comment: memcpy won't work, because he effectively needs to copy sequences of bytes, not just fill the whole block with a single byte.

Comment: You can fill as many bytes of one contiguous piece of memory with a direct copy of another contiguous piece of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure how you set 4 bytes in a row, but if you want to fill memory with just one byte over an over again, you can use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/).

> ```
> void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
> ```
>
> **Fill block of memory**
>
> Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by `ptr` to the specified value (interpreted as an `unsigned char`).

Comment: I don't want to fill memory with one byte. There're four bytes in `int32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a limited amount of values in your background parameter (or even better, only on), maybe you should try to allocate a static vector, and simply use memcpy.

```
const int32_t sBackground = 1234;
static vector <int32_t> sInitalizedBuffer(n, sBackground);

    const X::int_vec_t& X::process( const SOME_DATA& data )
    {
        // the following one string takes 30% of total time of #process function
        std::memcpy( (void*) data[0], (void*) sInitalizedBuffer[0], n * sizeof(sBackground));

        // some processing
        // ...

        return buffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested std::fill with g++ with full optimizations (SSE etc.. enabled):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <inttypes.h>

int32_t a[5000000];

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    std::fill(a,a+5000000,0xAABBCC00);
    return a[3];
}
```

and the inner loop looked like:

```
L2:
    movdqa  %xmm0, -16(%eax)
    addl    $16, %eax
    cmpl    %edx, %eax
    jne L2
```

Looks like 0xAABBCC00 x 4 was loaded into xmm0 and is being moved 16-bytes at a time.

Comment: I'm curious, why is this code which uses comparisons and conditional jumps still faster than `REPNZ STOS` or similar?

Comment: @Philipp: it copies 16 bytes at a time. Comparisons and conditional jumps aren't necessarily expensive. It depends a lot on the context, what other instructions are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

the vs2013 and vs2015 can optimize a plain for-loop to a `rep stos` instruction. It's the fastest way to fill a buffer. You can specify the `std::fill` for your type like this:

```
namespace std {
    inline void fill(vector<int>::iterator first, vector<int>::iterator last, int value){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < last - first; i++)
            first[i] = value;
    }
}
```

BTW. To have the compiler do the optimization, the buffer must be accessed by the subscript operator.

It will not work on the gcc and clang. They both will compile the code to a conditional jump loop. It runs as slow as the original `std::fill`. And though the `wchar_t` is 32-bit, the `wmemset` does not have an assemble implement likes the `memset`. So you have to write assemble code to do the optimization.

Answer (score -2):

It might be a bit non portable but you could use an overlapping memory copy.
Fill the first four bytes with the pattern you want and use memcpy().

```
int32* p = (int32*) malloc( size );
*p = 1234;
memcpy( p + 4, p, size - 4 );
```

don't think you can get much faster

Comment: It's not supported.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387654/why-is-there-no-z80-like-ldir-functionality-in-c-c-rtl

Comment: It may not be "supported" but it works in vs2008. I can provide source if needed. I also can't find what you're referring to in the linked page.

Comment: Overlapping memcpy's is a well-known bug, and to recommend them is bad advice.  memmove is the correct call to use for overlapping regions.  "It's not supported but it works" is for engraving on tombstones.

Comment: Sorry, you're misinformed. It is not a bug. Some have called it a bug because they don't comprehend the consequences of the code they wrote. There are explicit warnings to use memmove() if this is not the desired behavior. It works *as designed* using the bulk copy operation of the CPU.

Comment: I double checked and this has been changed to 'not defined behavior' since I last read the documentation. If the poster really wants the fastest way to accomplish his task this is it. To be safe he should compile a program using memcpy and extract the assembler source code and use it. That will prevent the current behavior from being deprecated or changed and breaking his program.

Comment: I'm a bit late... but he could just do a static link or even copy+paste the memcpy source rather than decompiling (or browsing an assembly listing or) his own program in order to get the assembler...

Comment: memcpy is always compiled to assembler as 'rep movsb'. Realistically this will not ever be changed. It would be much less efficient code and there's already memmove() to handle that case. I see no problem with recommending undefined behavior that will never be changed because a committee (and some purists) are being pedantic. Will makes a good point though. A bit of inline assembler using 'stos' would be clearer, more efficient, and less likely to cause issues if the code were ported to another processor.

Comment: Wrong. Modern `memcpy` implementations use SSE/AVX/AVX-512 instead of `rep movsb` to copy 16/32/64 bytes at the same time and achieve much higher performance